# Javascript id data store in php variable

Tags: javascript, php

how to store id="hello" data inside the php varible

```
 document.getElementById("product_category_id").innerHTML = response.product_category;
```

iwant to store this product_catory data into php variable

Comment: simply use AJAX

Comment: how  to use ajax

Comment: for start : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: then : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX